Harmonic 1-forms on a solid torus
What is the basis of harmonic 1-forms on a solid torus $M$ in $S^3$. I believe that it should be 1-dimensional since $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and there should be a unique harmonic 1-form that follows the central circle, but I'm not very familiar with Hodge theory on open manifolds or those with boundary.
Any literature references where harmonic 1-forms on a solid torus in $S^3$ are studied would also be appreciated.

Since the complement of $M$ is a knot complement (also a homology circle) maybe there has been some interest in harmonic 1-forms on knot complements that would also be relevant.
